# Buttons that change the default order of items. How can this work?

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to make these two buttons in the index.html to function.

```html
<div class="align-buttons">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{{ url_for('root', ordering_by='rating') }}">Ordering by rating</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{{ url_for('root', ordering_by='release_year') }}">Ordering by release year</a>
</div>`
```

What changes do I have to make? The default ordering is date_created and I need ordering_by=rating and ordering_by=release_year.

```py
    @app.route("/home/")
    @app.route("/")
    def root():    
        page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
        movies = Movie.query.order_by(Movie.date_created.desc()).paginate(per_page=5, page=page)
        return render_template("index.html", movies=movies)`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to accept the order parameter for the root route. I think the easiest way would be to do it like this:

```py
from flask import redirect, url_for, render_template

@app.route("/home")
@app.route("/")
def root():
    return redirect(url_for('root', ordering_by='date_created')


@app.route("/home/<ordering_by>")
@app.route("/<ordering_by>")
def root(ordering_by):    
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    movies = None
    match ordering_by:
        case 'rating':
            movies = Movie.query.order_by(Movie.rating.desc())
        case 'release_year':
            movies = Movie.query.order_by(Movie.release_year.desc())
        case 'date_created':
            movies = Movie.query.order_by(Movie.date_created.desc())
        case _:
            movies = Movie.query.all() 
    return render_template("index.html", movies=movies.paginate(per_page=5, page=page)
```

The Structural Pattern Matching (case/match) I used is only available in Python 3.10 and newer.

Don't pin me on the exact syntax, I didn't try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```js
#ok
@app.route("/home")
@app.route("/")
def root():
    page = request.args.get("page", 1, type=int)
    movies = Movie.query.order_by(Movie.date_created.desc()).paginate(per_page=5, page=page)
    return render_template("index.html", movies=movies)

@app.route("/home/<ordering_by>")
@app.route("/<ordering_by>")
def home(ordering_by):    
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    movies = None
    match ordering_by:
        case 'rating':
            movies = Movie.query.order_by(Movie.rating.desc())
        case 'release_year':
            movies = Movie.query.order_by(Movie.release_year.desc())
        case 'date_created':
            movies = Movie.query.order_by(Movie.date_created.desc())
    return render_template("index.html", movies=movies.paginate(per_page=5, page=page))
```

```html
<!--Changed root to home.-->
<div class="align-buttons">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{{ url_for('home', ordering_by='rating') }}">Ordering by rating</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{{ url_for('home', ordering_by='release_year') }}">Ordering by release year</a>
</div>
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.